# How to store a file uploaded with vichUploaderBundle?

Tags: file, symfony, upload

I'm working with Symfony 3.2.*

**The file is correctly selected in the web page, when I dump $request, file name and its size appear, but the file is not put in a folder in my project, how can I use in my controller to get this one (the file content I mean) ?**

In my entity :

```
/**
 * NOTE: This is not a mapped field of entity metadata, just a simple property.
 *
 * @Vich\UploadableField(mapping="product_image", fileNameProperty="imageName", size="imageSize")
 *
 * @var File
 */
private $imageFile;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
 *
 * @var string
 */
private $imageName;
```

In my view :

```html
<form class="form-horizontal" action="{{ path('thepouk_admin_gestion_themes_enreg_publier') }}" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">

<div class="form-group">
  <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="filebutton">Image</label>
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <input id="filebutton" name="image" class="input-file" type="file">
  </div>
</div>
<button id="singlebutton" name="nouveau_publier" class="btn btn-success"> ADD </button>
    
</form>
```

In my config.yml :

```js
vich_uploader:
    db_driver: orm
    mappings:
        product_image:
            uri_prefix: /images/products
            upload_destination: '%kernel.root_dir%/../web/images/products'
            inject_on_load: false
            delete_on_update: true
            delete_on_remove: true
```

In my Controller

```js
public function saveNewThingAction(Request $request){
      $th = new Thing();
      $theme->setImageFile($request->request->get('image'));
      $theme->setImageName($request->request->get('image'));
      $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
      $em->persist($th);
      $em->flush();
      return $this->render('PRBundle:Things:new.html.twig');
    }
```

Comment: do you want to use temp file content before upload ?

Comment: why? what's the difference with a solution without it?

Comment: did you try with this : `$request->files->get('fileFieldName');`

Comment: It works !! thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can touch request object with files method.

```
$request->files->get('fileFieldName');
```

Answer (score 0):

As you have posted only parts of your entity class this is just a guess. Have you added the `Uploadable` annotation to your entity?

See the [documentation](https://github.com/dustin10/VichUploaderBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/usage.md#step-2-link-the-upload-mapping-to-an-entity):

> First, annotate your class with the Uploadable annotation. This is really like a flag indicating that the entity contains uploadable fields.

e.g.

```
<?php

namespace Acme\DemoBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\File;
use Vich\UploaderBundle\Mapping\Annotation as Vich;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @Vich\Uploadable
 */
class Product
{
...
}
```

Comment: Yes I have added it.